# AEM dispatcher redirects - Apache rewrite rules for encoded URL is not working

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, aem, dispatcher

I'm adding multiple entries in my dispatcher rewrite files. One of them is -

```
RewriteRule ^/myvanity$  https://www.somedomain.com/path/my-page.html?nextUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.urlencoder.org%2F [NC,NE,R=301]
```

here, the issue is that if I try to access my vanity URL - `www.mydomain.com/myvanity` it is redirected to:

```
https://www.somedomain.com/path/my-page.html?nextUrl=httpsAFFwww.urlencoder.orgF
```

**The encoded part of the URL here is incorrect. The decoding is not required as part of the redirect & even after it is decoded, it's not correct.**

It should be - `https://www.somedomain.com/path/my-page.html?nextUrl=https://www.urlencoder.org/`

Rewrite Rule flag documentation referred - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Please note:
All other formats of rewrite rules(samples mentioned below) are working:

```
RewriteRule ^/myvanity-2$ https://www.otherdomain.com/other-path/other-page.html [NC,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/myvanity-3$ /other-path-2/other-page.html [NC,NE,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/myvanity-4$ https://www.otherdomain.com/other-path/other-page.html/#some-value [NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Why are you using Apache rewrites instead of the OOB AEM vanities?

Comment: curious, did you try this? - RewriteRule ^/myvanity$  https://www.somedomain.com/path/my-page.html?nextUrl=https:\/\/www.urlencoder.org\/ [NC,NE,R=301]